# How to make types.Implements work properly with the signature that uses imported types?

Tags: go

`types.Implements(impl1, iface)` returns `false`, when interface definition signature uses some type, and possible implementation lies in another package and needs to import that type.

Project structure

```
awesome
├── main.go
├── pkg1
│   └── file.go
└── pkg2
    └── file.go
```

i.e., there's package `main` in the `awesome` folder.

**`awesome/pkg1/file.go`**

```
package pkg1

import (
    "context"
)

// Interface generic object
type Interface interface {
    Method(context.Context) string
}

// Implementation1 implementation of Interface
type Implementation1 struct{}

// Method ...
func (Implementation1) Method(context.Context) string {
    return ""
}
```

**`awesome/pkg2/file.go`** looks like

```
package pkg2

import (
    "context"
)

// Implementation2 implementation for pkg1.Interface
type Implementation2 struct{}

// Method ...
func (Implementation2) Method(context.Context) string {
    return ""
}
```

And now **`awesome/main.go`**

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"
    "fmt"
)

var fset = token.NewFileSet()

func getPath() string {
    gopath := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
    if len(gopath) == 0 {
        usr, err := user.Current()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        gopath = filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, "go")
    }
    return filepath.Join(gopath, "src")
}

func getTypes(path string) *types.Package {
    fullpath := filepath.Join(getPath(), path)
    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, fullpath, nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        config := &types.Config{
            Importer: importer.Default(),
        }
        info := types.Info{
            Types: map[ast.Expr]types.TypeAndValue{},
        }
        var files []*ast.File
        for _, file := range pkg.Files {
            files = append(files, file)
        }
        typeInfo, err := config.Check(path, fset, files, &info)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        return typeInfo
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    p1 := getTypes("awesome/pkg1")
    p2 := getTypes("awesome/pkg2")

    iface := p1.Scope().Lookup("Interface").(*types.TypeName).Type().(*types.Named).Underlying().(*types.Interface)
    impl1 := p1.Scope().Lookup("Implementation1").Type()
    impl2 := p2.Scope().Lookup("Implementation2").Type()
    fmt.Println("Implementation1 implements Interface", types.Implements(impl1, iface))
    fmt.Println("Implementation2 implements Interface", types.Implements(impl2, iface))
}
```

Program output:

```
$ go install awesome
$ awesome
Implementation1 implements Interface true
Implementation2 implements Interface false
```

It happens because of imported type `context.Context`. It works fine and returns `true` in the second case when I change `Method`'s argument type to `string`, `int`, `byte`, whatever or just remove it. What am I doing wrong?

@mkopriva answer actually put me into right direction: different types checking produces different types, that's why `Implements` fails on non-basic types. We just need to reuse objects for type checking: this `main.go` actually works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"
)

var fset = token.NewFileSet()
var config = &types.Config{
    Importer: importer.Default(),
}
var typeInfo = &types.Info{    
    Types:      map[ast.Expr]types.TypeAndValue{},
    Defs:       nil,
    Uses:       nil,
    Implicits:  nil,
    Selections: nil,
    Scopes:     nil,
    InitOrder:  nil,
}

func getPath() string {
    gopath := os.Getenv("GOPATH")
    if len(gopath) == 0 {
        usr, err := user.Current()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        gopath = filepath.Join(usr.HomeDir, "go")
    }
    return filepath.Join(gopath, "src")
}

func getTree(path string) *ast.Package {
    fullpath := filepath.Join(getPath(), path)
    pkgs, err := parser.ParseDir(fset, fullpath, nil, parser.ParseComments)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        return pkg
    }
    return nil
}

func getTypes(pkg *ast.Package, path string) *types.Package {

    var files []*ast.File
    for _, file := range pkg.Files {
        files = append(files, file)
    }
    typeInfo, err := config.Check(path, fset, files, typeInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return typeInfo
}

func main() {
    const pkg1Path = "awesome/pkg1"
    t1 := getTree(pkg1Path)
    p1 := getTypes(t1, pkg1Path)
    const pkg2Path = "awesome/pkg2"
    t2 := getTree(pkg2Path)
    p2 := getTypes(t2, pkg2Path)

    iface := p1.Scope().Lookup("Interface").(*types.TypeName).Type().(*types.Named).Underlying().(*types.Interface)
    impl1 := p1.Scope().Lookup("Implementation1").Type()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", impl1.(*types.Named).Method(0).Name())
    impl2 := p2.Scope().Lookup("Implementation2").Type()
    fmt.Println("Implementation1 implements Interface", types.Implements(impl1, iface))
    fmt.Println("Implementation2 implements Interface", types.Implements(impl2, iface))
}
```

We just need to share `*types.Config` and `*types.Info` in order for the checking procedure to deal with once imported type (which is represented as an object) rather than to register it again as a new object.

Comment: I've copied and run your code, both return false (not true and false like your output), which is correct since context.Context is not pkg1.Arg. Please provide the exact code you're running or else we can't tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: To clarify, impl1 and impl2 both *do not* implement pkg1.Interface because their argument type to the Method method is different from the one specified in the Interface.

Comment: @mkopriva I am sorry, I got this behaviour from another example but then found the same behaviour with imported types. Fixed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour or if it's a bug but, if you dig through the source you'll find that the `types.Implements` "fails" here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/types/predicates.go#L282-L287

As you can see from the comment the comparison will return true only if the

> type names originate in the same type declaration

but if you add print statements there to check the x, y values you'll see that it compares two *different pointers* to `types.Named` value of the same type `context.Context`. The fact that the type info is allocated twice is equivalent to the named types *not* originating in the same declaration. The reason that you have two instances of the same named type is becuase you're parsing and checking the two packages separately.

So the solution is to parse and check both of the packages together. I'm not sure if this is a viable solution for you or not but one thing you can do is to declare a third package that imports the two packages and parse and check this third package.

For example:

```
awesome
├── main.go
├── pkg1
│   └── file.go
├── pkg2
│   └── file.go
└── pkg3
    └── file.go
```

Then the pkg3 contents would look like this:

**`awesome/pkg3/file.go`**

```
package pkg3

import (
    _ "awesome/pkg1"
    _ "awesome/pkg2"
)
```

And your main like this:

**`awesome/main.go`** (I've added only the changes that need to be made to the original)

```
func getTypes(path string) *types.Package {

    // ...

    for _, pkg := range pkgs {
        config := &types.Config{
            Importer: importer.For("source", nil),
        }

        // ...
    }
    return nil
}

// ...

func main() {
    p3 := getTypes("awesome/pkg3")

    p1 := p3.Imports()[0]
    p2 := p3.Imports()[1]

    // ...
}
```